# Reload ou Refresh DataTables

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, jquery-datatables

Bom dia,

Tenho um DataTables que é carregado por um WHILE que vem de uma QUERY no qual monte no começo da minha pagina por PHP.

Meu problema é quando preciso inserir ou editar alguma informação que vai nesse Table no HTML, pois não posso dar um refresh em toda a página somente na Table e seria esse meu problema.

Alguém saberia me informar como faço pra carregar novamente as informações que vem dessa QUERY no PHP para a minha Table?

Faço a chamada da inserção ou edição por AJAX e gostaria que acontecesse isso no SUCCESS da requisição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Montagem da minha Table:
                                                
                                                    Cadastro de Acesso

```
                                                <!-- MONTAGEM DO CABEÇALHO DA TABLE -->
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr class="bg-light">                                                          
                                                        <th>Cód. Acesso</th>
                                                        <th>Crachá OBER</th>
                                                        <th>Tipo Operação</th>
                                                        <th>Tipo Transporte</th>
                                                        <th>Placa do Veículo</th>
                                                        <th>Nome Empresa</th>
                                                        <th>Está na Empresa?</th>
                                                        <th>Cod. Autorizador</th>
                                                        <th>Nome Autorizador</th>
                                                        <th>Cód. Depto. Autor.</th>
                                                        <th>Nome Depto. Autor.</th>
                                                        <th>Dt. Entrada</th>
                                                        <th>Dt. Saída</th>
                                                        <th>Dt. Liberação</th>
                                                        <th>Dt. Limite Libe.</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <!-- FIM DO CABEÇALHO -->


                                                <!-- MONTAGEM DO CORPO DA TABLE -->
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <?php while (oci_fetch($stid_tables)) { ?>
                                                        <tr ng-repeat="ln in lista" class="ng-scope">                                                               
                                                        <td><?php echo $COD_ACESSO2; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $COD_CRACHA_OBER; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $TIPO_OPERACAO; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $DESC_TIPOTRANSPORTE; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $PLACA_VEICULO; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $NOME_EMPRESA; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $ATIVO_NAEMPRESA; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $COD_AUTORIZADOR; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $NOME_AUTORIZADOR; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $COD_LOCALIZACAO; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $DPTO_AUTORIZADOR; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $DT_ENTRADA; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $DT_SAIDA; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $DT_LIBERACAO; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $DT_LIMITELIBERACAO; ?></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    <?php } ?> 
                                                </tbody>
                                                <!-- FIM DO CORPO -->
                                            </table>
```

Montagem do meu AJAX:

```
            //FUNÇÃO DE INSERIR E EDITAR CADASTRO DE ACESSO
            $("#btnInserirAcesso").click(function() {
                //VARIAVEL DE CONTROLE DE INSERÇÃO DE NOVO ACESSO OU SE É EDIÇÃO DE UM ACESSO JÁ EXISTENTE
                var INSERIR_NOVO = $INSERIR_NOVO_ACESSO;

                $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "COD_VISITANTE2").attr("value", "<?php print $COD_VISITANTE ;?>").appendTo("#cadAcesso");
                $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "RH_IN_FILIAL").attr("value", "<?php echo $RH_IN_FILIAL; ?>").appendTo("#cadAcesso");
                $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "RH_IN_MATRIZ").attr("value", "<?php echo $RH_IN_MATRIZ; ?>").appendTo("#cadAcesso");
                $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "ERP_IN_FILIAL").attr("value", "<?php echo $ERP_IN_FILIAL; ?>").appendTo("#cadAcesso");
                $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "COD_USUARIO").attr("value", "<?php echo get_info_session(2, 'USU_IN_CODIGO'); ?>").appendTo("#cadAcesso");

                //EDITAR CADASTRO
                if ( INSERIR_NOVO == 'N' ) {
                    if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja alterar este registro?')) {
                       $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "ACAO").attr("value", "UA").appendTo("#cadAcesso");

                        var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#cadAcesso'));

                        $.ajax({url: '<?php echo $path_dir;?>apps/portaria/crud.php',
                                type: 'POST', 
                                data: formData,
                                dataType: 'html',
                                mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                                processData: false,
                                cache: false,
                                contentType: false,

                                //RETORNO OK
                                success: function(data) {
                                    if ( data == 'OK' ) {
                                        alert('Acesso Nº[' + document.getElementById("inputCodAcesso").value + '] alterado com sucesso!'); 

                                        //location.reload();  
                                        //$('#tabela_cadvisit').ajax.reload();                           
                                    } else {
                                        alert(data);
                                    };  
                                },

                                //RETORNO ÑOK
                                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, data) {
                                    alert('erro');
                                }
                        });

                        return false; 
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    };
```

Comment: Qual é o retorno de `data` no success?

Comment: @Sam é sempre 'OK' caso positivo.

        V_TXT_RETORNO := 'OK';
        
        RETURN(V_TXT_RETORNO);

Trato isso pelo banco de dados Oracle.

No crud.php chamo todas as minhas alterações de banco.

Comment: Entendi, mas onde é que vc edita ou insere dados da tabela?

Comment: Sempre trato pelo banco de dados, caso de algum tipo de erro na execução do INSERT por exemplo, o banco me retorna uma STRING já com o erro reclamado no banco.

No caso de execução sem erro só emito um 'OK' mesmo de retorno.

Comment: Perguntei onde vc edita ou insere dados no datatables. Tem algum formulário pra isso?

Comment: Sim por esse <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="cadAcesso" method="POST">

Comment: Blz, a questão de inserir é tranquilo de fazer, mas a de "editar" é mais complicado. Como vc está selecionando a linha que quer editar e como está puxando as informações dessa linha?

Comment: Para edição estou no click do btnEditar selecionando a chave da minha tabela assim, por JS:
if ( $("#tabela_cadvisit tr.selected").length >= 1 ) { 

Chamo um AJAX que nesse CRUD.PHP executo uma QUERY e no success vou inserindo os valores nos campos do meu modal $('#inputCodAcesso').val(data.COD_ACESSO2);

Retornados por datatype:'json'.

No fim dou um modal(show)

Comment: @Sam esqueci de comentar na descrição da minha dúvida, que preciso dar um refresh ou reload no DataTables, quando sair do meu modal. O success que me referi na questão é o success do insert do meu modal que abre quando clico em inserir ou editar. Desculpe pela falta de informações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai fazer o seguinte:

O código PHP que carrega os dados do datatables (onde tem `<?php while (oci_fetch($stid_tables)) { ?>`) você irá colocar num arquivo `.php` separado e fazer um include no `tbody`:

```
<tbody>
  <?php include ('tabela.php'); ?>
</tbody>
```

Esse mesmo arquivo `.php` será de onde você irá fazer um AJAX para recarregar a table após fechar a modal de inserir ou editar.

Ao fechar a modal, chame a função abaixo:

```
function recarregar(){
   $('#example tbody').load("tabela.php", function(data){
      $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
      $('#example tbody').empty().append(data);
      $('#example').DataTable();
   });
}
```

A função irá destruir o datatables, esvaziar o `tbody`, inserir os dados atualizados e iniciar novamente o plugin.

No arquivo `.php`, para fazer o `while`, será preciso fazer a query no banco de dados para retornar os dados.

Comment: Boa tarde Sam. 


Para carregar o DataTables funcionou perfeito, mas quando chamo o recarregar() dentro do success do meu AJAX no insert/edit da minha modal, ele não executa o LOAD: 

$('#tbodyCadVisit tbody').load('<?php echo $path_dir;?>apps/portaria/visitantes_veiculos/tbody_cad_visit.php', function(data){


 Mas também não me emite erro algum. 

Veja abaixo o que estou fazendo de código.

Comment: Bom dia, amigo. Coloque um `console.log(data)` na function do .load para ver o que mostra o console.

Comment: Veja tb qual a versão do jQuery que vc está usando.

Comment: Boa tarde Sam. Consegui chamar meu arquivo .PHP com a QUERY pra carregar novamente o DataTable, só que ao carregar novamente o corpo da Table, o cabeçalho perde a configuração inicial dos dados e fica desalinhado com o corpo da Table.

Comment: Veja como estou executando dentro do LOAD:
        $('#tabela_cadvisit').remove();    
        $('#tabela_cadvisit').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#tabela_cadvisit tbody').empty().append(data);

        $('#tabela_cadvisit').DataTable({});

Comment: Vc tah removendo o elemento, assim vai dar erro mesmo

Comment: Sam bom dia, agora está funcionando corretamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.